# clone on file input form not working

Tags: jquery, html, forms, clone

When adding a new form to submit a slider I use .clone and .append/insertBefore (Jquery) to make the new the forms. However, my function for the file input only works on the original form. Im trying to make the code take the name of the file on the .change and to insert into a text field. Can you help me figure out why this wouldn't work for the clone?

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
    <div class = "add_contCall">
    <p>Nuevo Slider</p>
    <button class = "btn btn-primary addFrom_slide">+</button>
</div>

    {!!Form::open(array('url' => 'admin/new_slider', 'files' => true, 'class' => 'newForm')) !!}
            {!! Form::hidden('position', null, ['class' => 'form-control slide_position']) !!}
        <div class = "form-group">
            {!!Form::label('title', 'Title:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
            {!!Form::text('title', null, ['class'=> 'input-mini'])!!}

            {!!Form::label('title', 'Description:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
            {!!Form::text('description', null, ['class'=> 'input-mini '])!!}
        </div>

        <div class = "form-group">
            {!!Form::label('title', 'Link:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
            {!!Form::text('link', null, ['class'=> 'input-mini'])!!}

            <div class = "image_group">
            {!!Form::label('title', 'Image:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
            {!!Form::text('empty', null, ['class'=> 'input-mini file_name'])!!}
            <div class = "btn btn-primary image_uploader">
                <span>Anadir Imagen</span>
                {!! Form::file('image', ['class' => 'image_']) !!}
            </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        {!! Form::close() !!}

        <div class = "form-group fg_save">
            <button class = "btn btn-default sub_add">Guardar</button>
            <hr>
        </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
    $('.image_uploader').on('click',function() {
    var $input = $(this).children("input:file");
    var $filename = $(this).siblings('.file_name');
    $input.change(function (){
        var fileName = $(this).val();
        var reFry = fileName.substr(12);
        $filename.val(reFry);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `clone` to clone elements that have event listeners bound to them (or their child elements), then you have to pass in parameters, the second of which has to be true - e.g. `$element.clone(true,true)` - so the event listeners/data get cloned as well, as described in the API:

https://api.jquery.com/clone/#clone-withDataAndEvents-deepWithDataAndEvents

An alternate solution is to delegate the form events to a non-changing parent element so you won't have to worry about this at all, e.g.:

```
$('some-non-changing-parent-element').on('click','.image-uploader',function() {
    var $input = $(this).children("input:file");
    var $filename = $(this).siblings('.file_name');
    $input.change(function (){
        var fileName = $(this).val();
        var reFry = fileName.substr(12);
        $filename.val(reFry);
    });
});
```